# websocket not calling frontend

Tags: node.js, express, sockets

Server

```
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server: server });

app.post("/webhook", async (req, res) => {
  const { status, result_url } = req.body;
  if (status === "done") {
    wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
      console.log("Webhook called: " + result_url);
      ws.send("I am from backend post" + result_url);
    });
  } else {
    res.json({ output: "Webhook response" });
  }
});
```

Client

```
const socket = new WebSocket("wss://alie.polyverse.app");

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener("open", function (event) {
  console.log("Connected to WS Server");
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
  console.log("Message from server ", event.data);
});
```

Here is my websocket code.I am calling frontend when i get webhook call.
it is giving "Connected to WS Server"
But, server is not calling frontend after message received.What can be the issue ?

Please take a look.

Comment: Does it really make sense to install a new `connection` handler to your wss server every time a POST to `/webhook` is made?  I would expect the `wss.on` call would be made outside to install a connection handler.  Not sure how you expect the websocket connection to be associated with the `POST /webhook` request.

Comment: How can write api call inside websocket function ?

Comment: This server doesn't create the websocket connection handler until the webhook is called (for some strange reason). Did you call the webhook? Do you want it to handle websocket connections *all the time* or not until the webhook is called?

Comment: You've currently written a websocket connection handler inside an API handler (this makes not much sense).  To ask _How can write api call inside websocket function?_ would be the reverse, and makes even less sense.  I feel like there should be two root-level handlers installed.  One that handles HTTP(S) requests (added with `app.post("/webhook"`...) and one that accepts websocket connections (added with `wss.on("connection"`...).  Add a log message in the server in the "connection" handler to see if the connection handler is happening. The `ws.send` looks fine.

Comment: Can you please edit the code ? I am new to web socket

Comment: No connection not happening

Comment: You're referring to _server_ and _frontend_ in your description, but you've labelled both of your code blocks as _Client_.  I assume the top one is meant to be labelled _Server_ and the other is meant to be labelled _frontend_?

Comment: My bad, Coorected now. upper one seerver

Comment: Missing numerous things from your server.  Like: `express = require('express'); http = require('http'); WebSocket = require('ws');`  (I'm guessing you're using `ws` for `WebSocket`?)  Also, missing some kind of a `listen` calll.  This would be better if it were a minimal (complete) example.

Answer (score 0):

```
wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
  console.log("establish websocket connection");
  ws.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log("received: %s", message);
  });
});

app.post("/webhook", async (req, res) => {
  const { status, result_url } = req.body;
  if (status === "done") {
    // wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
    //   console.log("Webhook called: " + result_url);
    //   ws.send("I am from backend post" + result_url);
    // });
    wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
      if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        console.log(result_url);
        client.send(result_url);
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.json({ output: "Webhook response" });
  }
});
```